# Does Comment not work with unicode value in java, if not then why?

Tags: java

When i use new line character in comment like this `//System.out.print("\n Hi");` no problem in compilation.
But when i try to use Unicode value instead of special character for new line like this `//System.out.print("\u000d HI");` it omits Compilation Error?
Does unicode value not support in comment, if no then Why? 
Please Explain

Comment: Your question is unclear. If it's in a comment, what is the meaning of "it is working"? How is it "not working" when a comment is ignored by the compiler?  What are you expecting should happen?

Comment: Interesting `System.out.print(\u000d "HI");` compiles and works but `//System.out.print(\u000d "HI");` has a compile error as the `\u000d` seems to be wrong interpretted

Comment: Unicode sequences (such as `\u000d`) are processed _very early_ by the compiler.  When you use one, it is replaced with the equivalent character before the compiler starts parsing anything.  To see what I mean, try putting `System.out.println(\u0022Hello");` in a program (0x0022 is the code for a double quote mark).

Comment: @ScaryWombat Shouldn't be surprising... both cases work exactly as if you had a newline in your code instead of `\u000d`.  In the first example, it's like you had `System.out.print("HI");` but put the parameter on a new line, which is fine in Java.  In the second case, the newline terminates the comment, so it's like you had `"HI");` all by itself on a line, which is bad syntax.

Comment: By the way, "omit" means to leave out, so you said the compiler leaves out the Compilation Error.  I think you mean "emit".  I don't normally harp on misspellings, but occasionally a misspelling can reverse the entire meaning of a sentence.

Comment: @ajb Yep **not** interesting when I think about it.

Comment: @ajb thanks for explanation, you mean first compiler put unicode value then go for comment like this //System.out.print(";
Hi");

Comment: Pretty much.  The compiler first changes `\u000d` to a newline.  Then it parses the comment, and since a comment ends at the end of the line, the newline that it put in earlier, when it saw your `\u000d`, will end the comment.  Basically, it's a bad idea to use `\uxxxx` for any character in the range 0000 to 007f, because it's not useful and can have surprising results.

Comment: @ajb Thanks again